# change html p tag text according to a clicked button

Tags: javascript, html, string, innerhtml

I have a

image with id = "b1" and html p tag that shows a number or a text

When the user click the image I want to see the value of its second parameter (here it is 1) added to the p tag inner html

Lets say p is first shown as HELLO, after clicking the image it should be shown as HELLO1

I used this code for the image

```
<img src="images/b_1.png" id="b1" onclick="buttonaction(this,1);"></img>
```

And the script is as follows

```
function buttonaction(id,imported){
id.src="images/b_3.png";
document.getElementById("main_display").innerhtml+=imported;

};
```

This did not work. I am new to this and look forward some explanation as well.

Comment: it's `innerHTML` not `innerhtml` js is case sensitive

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function buttonaction(id,imported){
id.src="images/b_3.png";
document.getElementById("main_display").innerHTML+=imported;

};
```

should work for you